# Is there a way to apply Frullani's formulas for this integral?

Tags: calculus

What's the best way to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}x\frac{\sin3x}x\cos ax\,dx$$
I thought about Frullani's formulas but they need $x$ in the denominator and I have $x^2$. Is there a way to apply Frullani's formulas in this case or this was a wrong path?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you need this for?

Comment: Hint: you might try to think of this integral as of a Fourier transform.

Comment: *Hint.* The Dirichlet integral immediately yields $$I(a):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos ax}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}|a|$$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Now using suitable trigonometric identities, check that your integral equals $$\frac{1}{4}(I(a+2) + I(a+4) - I(a-2) - I(a-4)).$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Interesting solution which does not need Fourier transform. I think you should propose it as a solution while the question is not closed... I am inclined to think that the way the integral is written invites to consider two "sinc" functions. But the OP doesn't say anything in particular if he/she is studying Fourier Transforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your integral as the real part of

$$3 \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin x}x \ . \ \frac{\sin3x}{3x}\right)e^{-i ax}\,dx$$

Making the change of variable $x=\pi t$, and setting $a=2u$, we have to compute the real part of :

$$I(u):=\frac{3\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t} \ . \ \frac{\sin3 \pi t}{3 \pi t}\right)e^{-i 2 \pi u t}\,dt$$

The above integral is the Fourier transform of a product of so-called "sinc" functions, therefore the convolution of their Fourier transforms which are known to be characteristic functions $\chi(u)$ and $\dfrac{1}{3}\chi(\dfrac{u}{3})$ where $\chi(u)=\Pi_{[-\frac12,\frac12]}$ , the other one being $\color{red}{\dfrac{1}{3}}\Pi_{[-\frac32,\frac32]}$ resp.

The convolution of  functions $\chi(u)$ and $\chi(\dfrac{u}{3})$ can be understood as the amount of light passing through the holes of two strips of paper (of size $3/2-(-3/2)=3$ and $1/2-(-1/2)=1$ resp.) when one of the strips (here the red one) slides over the other.

[image]

This process gives a kind of aztec pyramid (see figure below, where we have taken the $\frac13$ fraction into account).

Precisely, the result will be the even continuous function:

$$I(u)=\frac{3\pi}{2}.\color{red}{\frac13}\begin{cases}(u+2)&\text{if} -2<u<-1\\1&\text{if} -1<u<1\\(-u+2)& \text{if} \ \ 1<u<2\\0&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Taking into account the fact that $a=2u$, the integral becomes :

$$J(a):=\frac{\pi}{2}\begin{cases}(a/2+2)&\text{if} -4<a<-2\\1&\text{if} -2<a<2\\(-a/2+2)& \text{if} \ \ 2<a<4\\0&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

See figure below :

[image]

It will remain to switch back to parameter $a$.

(in fact, no need to take the real value of the result : it is naturally a real value...)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I've got $\pi/4\left\{\begin{aligned} 0, a\ge 4 \\ 4-a, 2\le a \le 4,\\ 2, -2 \le a \le 2,\\ 4+a, -4 \le a \le -2,\\ 0, a \le -4\\ \end{aligned} \right.$, is it correct?

Comment: I just see my error : right in the beginning, I have divided by 3 instead of multiplying by 3... and I get your factor $\pi/4$. Wow, I apologize for the numerous errors ! But at least we have got it... I have corrected this error.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about Frullani's formulas, can we somehow apply these formulas here?

Comment: IMHO, it is unlikely that they can be applied here.